# Callback OnStreamMessageHandler in Unity return only half of cyrillic string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to implement Agora.io text chat in Unity. Using SendStreamMessage method to send message and OnStreamMessageHandler callback to get the stream message. Everything works as expected when I send\receive latin alphabet string. But when I try to receive cyrillic string message, it gets only half of string. Is it some SDK bug or what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by sending text through json byte array